# Test fails with runAs, queueable and callout in specific org

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests, httpcalloutmock, queueable

Has anyone got an idea what could cause the following test to fail in one org and pass in another?

The error is `System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out` at `Class.QueueableCalloutTest.QueueableCallout.execute: line 31, column 1`

The orgs are both Partner Developer Orgs, from a single environment hub. Both have a namespace and are used for publishing packages.

I've checked the following settings are identical in setup

- Apex Test Execution -> Options
- Apex Settings
- Critical Updates
- User Interface

The failing test class:

```
@IsTest
public class QueueableCalloutTest {

    @IsTest static void testCallout() {

        Id profileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'].Id;

        User u = new User(Alias = 'example', Email = 'exampletestuser@example.com', EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', FirstName = 'Testing', LastName = 'Testing', LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', TimeZoneSidKey = 'Europe/London', LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', Username = 'exampletestuser@example.com', ProfileId = profileId);
        insert u;

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());

        System.runAs(u) {

            Test.startTest();
            System.enqueueJob(new QueueableCallout());
            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }

    public class QueueableCallout implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

        public void execute(QueueableContext ctx) {

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://maps.googleapis.com');
            req.setMethod('GET');
            HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
        }
    }

    public class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {

        public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {

            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

I think I've stripped it down to the bare minimum to reproduce the issue. The issue doesn't occur if the `System.runAs` call is removed. I understand that the `System.enqueueJob()` call counts as DML, but not why it might count as DML in one org and not another.

I've reviewed this Salesforce [help article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_dml.htm) but I don't think it explains the discrepancy.

There are some posts here where people are getting this error, and they do point to workarounds which I'm aware I could implement, but none point to why there might be a discrepancy which is what I'd like to understand.

Comment: Enquejob is not the issue, I think some DMl is occurring before the callout, can you post the code in the QueueableCallout class?

Comment: Thanks Rahul. The QueueableCallout class is an inner class to QueueableCalloutTest - you should be able to paste that class into any org and run the test.

Comment: Does the failing org has any triggers on user object which performs a DML?

Comment: Thanks Raul. No, there's no trigger, process builder or workflow on the User object. Also, the test still fails in this org if I remove the line "insert u;" (but passes if I remove the insert statement and the System.runAs())

Comment: Have you tried running tests after you have "Disable Parallel Apex Testing" option checked? (you can find this option on Setup -> Apex Test Execution -> Options)